# Xcode 8.21 View Hierachy debug displayed "White blank"

Tags: xcode

I'm using Objective-C and somehow, the 3th view hierarchy debug isn't working at all.

Xcode 8.21, iOS 10.2, Objective-C.

0 errors. Just nothing displayed in View Hierarchy debug mode.

I have tried both storyboard style & xib style.
Both not working.

Is this a common bug from Apple?

[image: work fine but not display correctly]